# Python application with both interactive and inline mode

Tags: python, python-cmd

I am trying to create a Python command-line app, which supports both interactive (currently using Cmd) and inline modes (like Python's `python -c`). Is there a good way to do it without duplicating the 'line parsing' code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Cmd.onecmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.onecmd) method:

> Interpret the argument as though it had been typed in response to the prompt.